# Magento 2: how to mark on grey sold out products

Tags: magento2

I want display products "out of stock" in product list but I want mark this product on grey and "sold out".
[image]

Anyone know how to do or any extension ?
@

I have file in

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

and this file list.phtml from app/ have 17mb

and file list.phtml from vendor have only 7mb

when I overwrote this file in app/ from vendor all styles have broken down.

in my file list.phtml (I have before):

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

I cannot found:

```
<div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
```

By default, my "sold out" product template is displayed in this way:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the **list.phtml** file from:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

to your theme location like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Then add the below code:

```
<?php if (!$_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <div class="out-of-stock"><span><?= __('Wyprzedane')?></span></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just after the below code:

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
```

and before the below the line:

```
<div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
```

Now you need to add some css for styling, add the below css to your css file:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .product.product-item{position: relative;}
    .out-of-stock {
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 10; 
        opacity: 0.5; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        background: #ffffff; 
        text-align: center;
    }
    .out-of-stock span {
        top: 50%;
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        background: #000000;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 10%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Then Final step:
Run the below commands if you add the css to less or css files:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f(if development or default mode) and
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (if production mode)
```

***Note: You can modify the css according to your requirement.***

Comment: I have update my topic